# is crossentropy loss of pytorch different than "categorical_crossentropy" of keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to mimic a pytorch neural network in keras.

I am confident that my keras version of the neural network is very close to the one in pytorch but during training, I see that the loss value of the pytorch network are much lower than the loss values of the keras network. I wonder if this is because I have not properly copied the pytorch network in keras or the loss computation is different in the two framework.

Pytorch loss definition:

```
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=args.lr, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=5e-4)
```

Keras loss definition:

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=.1, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
resnet.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

Note that all the layers in the keras network have been implemented with L2 regularization `kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4)`, also I used `he_uniform` initialization which I believe is default in pytorch, according to the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b64fc3c4b5d927928770f9b343eb845123367084/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L79).

The batch size for the two networks are the same: `128`.

In the pytorch version, I get loss values around `4.1209` which decreases to around `0.5`. In keras it starts around 30 and decreases to `2.5`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keras `categorical_crossentropy` by default uses `from_logits=False` which means it assumes `y_pred` contains probabilities (not raw scores) ([source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py)).  You can choose to use a softmax/sigmoid layer, just make sure to set the `from_logits` argument accordingly.

PyTorch `CrossEntropyLoss` accepts unnormalized scores for each class i.e., not probability ([source](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss)).  Thus, if using `CrossEntropyLoss` you should not use a softmax/sigmoid layer at the end of your model.

If this confuses you, please read [this discuss.pytorch post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/categorical-cross-entropy-loss-function-equivalent-in-pytorch/85165/11).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It answers the asked question but it mans that the loss computation is equivalent  in my case. Have you any idea why a network apparently similar to an other would give much higher loss values?

Comment: You will notice small difference but if this is too large (0.5 vs 2.5) then there is something wrong. Hard to tell without more information but you can verify if the batches fed to the networks are identical.

Comment: I just realized that the loss value printed in the pytorch code was only the categorical cross entropy! Whereas in the keras code, it is the sum of the categorcial cross entropy with the regularization term. I just disabled the weight decay in the keras code and the losses are now roughly the same. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the reason why the displayed losses in the two models was different is because Keras prints the sum of the cross entropy loss with the regularization term whereas in the pytorch model only the categorical cross entropy was printed.