# How is cross entropy loss work in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am experimenting with some of the pytorch codes. With cross entropy loss I found some interesting results and I have used both binary cross entropy loss and cross entropy loss of pytorch.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

X = torch.tensor([[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1]],dtype=torch.float)
softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)


bce_loss = nn.BCELoss()
ce_loss= nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

pred = softmax(X)

bce_loss(X,X) # tensor(0.)
bce_loss(pred,X) # tensor(0.3133)
bce_loss(pred,pred) # tensor(0.5822)

ce_loss(X,torch.argmax(X,dim=1)) # tensor(0.3133)
```

I expected the cross entropy loss for the same input and output to be zero. Here X, pred and torch.argmax(X,dim=1) are same/similar with some transformations. This reasoning only worked for `bce_loss(X,X) # tensor(0.)` where-else all other resulted in a loss greater than zero. I speculated the output for `bce_loss(pred,X)`, `bce_loss(pred,pred)` and `ce_loss(X,torch.argmax(X,dim=1))` should be zero.

What is the mistake here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is crossentropy loss of pytorch different than "categorical\_crossentropy" of keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437961/is-crossentropy-loss-of-pytorch-different-than-categorical-crossentropy-of-ker)

Answer (score 4):

The reason that you are seeing this is because `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` accepts logits and targets, a.k.a X should be logits, but is already between 0 and 1. `X` should be much bigger, because after softmax it will go between 0 and 1.

```
ce_loss(X * 1000, torch.argmax(X,dim=1)) # tensor(0.)
```

`nn.CrossEntropyLoss` works with logits, to make use of the log sum trick.

The way you are currently trying after it gets activated, your predictions become about `[0.73, 0.26]`.

Binary cross entropy example works since it accepts already activated logits. By the way, you probably want to use `nn.Sigmoid` for activating binary cross entropy logits. For the 2-class example, softmax is also ok.